# Trying to make a Java EE/JPA application run, but I keep getting errors from Observer

Tags: jakarta-ee, weld

I set up JPA with a MySQL data source, after hours of driver problems, this finally works.

Now, when I try to deploy it, I keep getting weld errors about Observer. I'm not sure what this means, I couldn't find anything about it.

I would be grateful if anybody can help me out.

---

Here's the error:

```
[2015-11-15 03:53:06,923] Artifact Artists:ear exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2015-11-15 03:53:06,923] Artifact Artists:ear exploded: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Artists_ear_exploded.ear\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Artists_ear_exploded.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.jboss.weld.security.NewInstanceAction.run(NewInstanceAction.java:33)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.Exceptions.rethrowException(Exceptions.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInvocationStrategy$SimpleMethodInvocationStrategy.invoke(MethodInvocationStrategy.java:129)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:306)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:284)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:262)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifySyncObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notify(ObserverNotifier.java:260)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:148)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:61)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:420)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.WeldStartService.start(WeldStartService.java:93)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractUnboundContext.<init>(Z)V
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.contexts.ThreadContext.<init>(ThreadContext.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldSEBeanRegistrant.registerWeldSEContexts(WeldSEBeanRegistrant.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    ... 21 more
"}}
```

Comment: NoSuchMethodError is very clear ... you have inconsistent jars ... in this case Weld. So find a version that has that method

Comment: @NeilStockton I found a weld-core version that has this method. http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jboss.weld/weld-core/2.1.0.Final/org/jboss/weld/context/AbstractBoundContext.java?av=f#26
2.1.0.Final. I added this one into my maven pom file and removed the old jar. It still doesn't work unfortunately..

Comment: so if it complains about NoSuchMethodError then it is NOT finding the new jar and has some other jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Neil Stockton for the help.

I removed the weld jars from my library and added the weld-core in my maven pom file.

Everything works after removing the weld jar files!